# UIGestureRecognizer in master/detail for diagonal movement interfering with sub view

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, diagonal

I have a master detail template application with a specific view that needs to have gestures disabled (specifically right swipe since that fires up the table view under the UISplitViewController). I have added the following code snippet to my view's ViewDidLoad and it appears to handle the swipe fine for up/down/right/left.  Problem is that a diagonal movement either bottom/left to top/right or top/left to bottom/right fires for some type of gesture and occasionally brings up the table view. If movement is slow it doesn't, but if a fast diagonal movement it interrupts my view drawing action.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer * recognizerR = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
recognizerR.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

recognizerR.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
recognizerR.delegate = self;

 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizerR];
}
```

I'm a bit new to IOS/Obj C programming so bear with me.